# Как завершить работу активности из SurfaceView

Tags: java, android

Как после проверки некоторого условия завершить работу активности из класса `SurfaceView`, который выполняется в этой активности и перейти в главную активность `MainActivity`? Допустим, условие такое `if (x==0){?}`. Как это написать?

Comment: Activity не наследуется от SurfaceView :)

Comment: Не так выразилась, класс

Comment: От вашего уточнения понятнее не стало, что вы имеете в виду. Но вообще переходы между activity происходят либо через intent и startActvity(intent), либо через команду finish() , если activity была открыта через startActivityForResult. Если вторая activity вызвана через просто startActivity, то по команде finish(), может и не вернуться в первую, так как первая может быть уже уничтожена.

Comment: У вас есть некая активити , в которой вы выводите SurfaceView и вы хотите вернуться в другую , которая ее вызвала ?

Comment: А причем тут SurfaceView? работа любой Anctivity завершается методом finish();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в конструкторе класса , наследуемого от `SurfaceView` передаете `Context`

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView{
  Context mContext;

public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
     mContext = context;
     ...
    }
 }
```

Когда необходимо закончить выполнение активити , вызвавшей этот `SurfaceView` делаете :

Для возврата назад по стеку вызовов:

```
    if (x==0) ((Activity) mContext).finish();
```

Для перехода к произвольной активити (в данном случае MainActivity ):

```
 if (x==0) {Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
             mContext.startActivity(intent);
             ((Activity) mContext).finish();
 }
```

Вызываете в `Activity` свое `SurfaceView` , например , так :

```
setContentView(new MySurfaceView(this));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это как раз то, что было нужно, спасибо, что поняли.